# Dockerfile LABEL from executable version

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to label my docker image with my app version from within my `Dockerfile` using the `LABEL` command.

I can write the version into a file with the following:

```
RUN /opt/app/foo --version > /var/app-version
```

`/var/app-version` would now contain a plaintext file with the application version inside, ready for use in my label.

Now I need a way to place this into a docker variable/arg such that I can do something like the following:

```
LABEL application_version=$APP_VERSION
```

Or perhaps there is another way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able set a label using content generated dynamically from something installed inside the container. You can set a label dynamically from your host environment using a build argument, like this:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest

ARG application_version=1
LABEL application_version=${application_version}
```

If I build the container like this:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

I will have:

```
$ docker inspect image myimage | jq '.[0].Config.Labels'
{
  "application_version": "1"
}
```

Whereas if I build the container like this:

```
docker build --build-arg application_version=3 -t myimage .
```

I will have:

```
$ docker inspect image myimage | jq '.[0].Config.Labels'
{
  "application_version": "3"
}
```

If you use the same build argument value to select the version of the
software you install in your container, you can ensure that the
installed version and the label match.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, could you elaborate on why we are not able to dynamically label from inside the Dockerfile, is this likely to be a feature in the future or is there a good reason for forbidding it?

Comment: I don't really have much to add. There's simply no facility for doing what you've asked. I don't work for (or develop for) Docker so I don't have any visibility into future features, but I would argue that the sort of information you want to use for a label should be provided by your image build environment rather than extracted from the image you're building (you should already know what version of the application you've put into the image).